# Not able to ping Ubuntu VM from host deployed using NAT

Tags: windows-7, ping, vmware-workstation, nat

I have Windows 7 as a host operating system and have created a Ubuntu VM using NAT Network configuration. IP Address of VM is `192.168.182.134`. However when I am trying to ping it using command from host operating system I am getting request timed out:

```
ping 192.168.182.134
```

I don’t want to switch to other network configuration such as host only or bridged connection. Is it possible to access it directly using NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Since [NAT networking](http://geek-university.com/vmware-player/configure-nat-networking/) in VMware creates a separate private network on the host system and a virtual machine gets its IP address on this private network from the virtual DHCP server, you should be able to ping your local machine. Perhaps the firewall is enabled in Windows 7?